# Why does this jQuery code checking all checkboxes not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<table class="responsive" id="products">
    <a href="#" id="checkAllProducts">Do it</a>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
</table>
```

​JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#checkAllProducts').click(function(){
    var checkbox = $('#products input:checkbox');
    checkbox.attr('checked',!checkbox.attr('checked'));
  });
});​
```

It's available for debugging [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UNqfv/3/).

Code works if I do `var checkbox = $('input:checkbox');`. Problem is likely to be in selector

This code should check all checkboxes after clicking link. But it doesn't do it. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know a table can contain any block level or inline element, as long as the table is properly formatted. The problem is that a table has to have stuff like `td`, `tr` and shit, to define it's lines and rows, and if you try:

```
<table class="responsive" id="products">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" id="checkAllProducts">Do it</a>
            <input type="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

it will work just fine, and then you can do:

```
$(function(){
  $('#checkAllProducts').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var checkbox = $('#products input[type="checkbox"]');
      checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UNqfv/13/)​​​

Answer (score 7):

Your HTML is invalid. You cannot put an `input` element directly inside a `table` element. The browser most likely auto-closes the table tag right when it finds that the next element must not follow a table tag - therefore the checkboxes cannot be found as childs of the `#products` selector.

```
<div class="responsive" id="products">
```

does the trick.

Furthermore, "checked" is a property, so you should use prop() to access it:

```
checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop('checked'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UNqfv/6/

Answer (score 1):

```
var checkbox = $('#products input:checkbox');
```

`checkbox` is not a single checkbox, you need to call `.each()` to do operation on all checkboxes..

Comment: Code works if I do `var checkbox = $('input:checkbox');`. Problem is in selector

Comment: +1 because you addressed the `.each`. In Niko (+1 as well)'s demo if you check the first checkbox and press "Do it", it'll set the others to the inverse of the first checkbox's checked value. Also, even though I really like shorthand selectors, `:checkbox` and other input selectors are classed as "deprecated" on jQuery 1.8 because they don't provide the native DOM [QSA](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) performance boost. `:(`

Answer (score 1):

html table element must be contain tr, td tag.

```
<table class="responsive" id="products">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" id="checkAllProducts">Do it</a></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and your selector code should be similar

```
var checkbox = $('#products tr td input:checkbox');
```

for debugging [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UNqfv/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this and it will work just fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#checkAllProducts').click(function(){
    var checkbox = $('input:checkbox');
    checkbox.attr('checked',!checkbox.attr('checked'));
});

});​
```

The reason being that you need to specify "all check bockes". At the moment with using the selector "$('#products input:checkbox');", you are only selecting check boxes with the id as "products". Your original code would work if you had an id attribute on every checkbox called "products". Instead, the selector I showed you above will select any checkbox type. Hopefully this helps, and the explanation is clear! Happy coding!